# Linux terminal very slow to load

Tags: linux, debian, terminal, xfce

I'm using debian-9 xfce. When I open terminal or open a new tab in terminal it takes 7/8 seconds to load. It was working fine but suddenly terminal started taking a long time to load. After opening terminal I just see empty screen and after few seconds everything appears. 
I don't think that this has happened after installing any particular package. Any suggestions?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Check the intializatiom files, e.g .bashrc, .zshrc, .bash_profile etc. May be it got too bit or some wrong commands...

Comment: Agreeing with @biswapriyo. Look in particular for network stuff (references to non-existing network shares, access to network resources...)

Comment: I have already checked .bashrc but nothing found wrong.